# How to search a item from a list?

Tags: python

Could anyone tell me why this code cannot work, please?

```
list=[5,9,2,5,13] 
item=input("Please enter the search item.")
found=false
for search = 0 to list.length -1
if item==list[search]:
found= True
next search
if found==True:
print("The item is in the list.")
else:
    print("The item is not in the list.")
```

Comment: It can't work because it's not really Python. I'd strongly recommend a structured tutorial, see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 1):

You should at least write in a better way, like:

```
lst=[5,9,2,5,13] 
item = int(input("Please enter the search item."))
found = False
for search in range(len(lst)):
    if item == (lst[search]):
        found = True
if found:
    print('{} is in the list'.format(item))
else:
    print('{} is not in the list'.format(item))
```

Comment: Using `range(len(lst))` to loop over a list is not what is considered as _pythonic_.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the syntax and if that is indeed python. I recommend you look up  a tutorial first.

However, this is how you can search for an element in your list:

```
list=[5,9,2,5,13] 
element = raw_input("Please enter the desired element")

if int(element) in list:  #note i've put int() because your list is made out of numbers rather than strings.
    print element + " is in the list"
else:
    print element + " is not in the list"
```

Answer (score -1):

That's what you're asking for:

```
value = int(input('Please enter a value to search: '))

if value in [5, 9, 2, 5, 13]:
    print('Item found.')
else:
    print('Item not found.')
```